# Losing Vue reactivity when passing object from Vuex Array between components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-props

I have two child components in my Main.vue:

- List view (list-comments) of all comments
- Detail view (list-comment) for a single item view

Depending on the value of **currentListView** its either shown the list or the detail view

**Main.vue: Here are the child-components for list / detail view:**

```
<template>
  <div id="list" v-if="enableListDrawer">
    <list-comments
      v-if="currentListView == 'comments'"
      :project="project"
      @showComment="showComment"
    />
    <list-comment
      v-else-if="currentListView == 'comment'"
      :selectedComment="selectedComment"
      @submitConversation="submitConversation"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentListView: "comments",
      selectedComment: {},
    };
  },
  computed: {
    projects() {
      return this.$store.getters.projects.filter(
        (o) => o._id == this.currentProjectToEdit
      );
    },
    project() {
      return this.$store.getters.projects
        .filter((o) => o._id == this.currentProjectToEdit)[0]
        .pages.filter((page) => page.url == window.location.href);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    showComment(comment) {
      this.selectedComment = comment;
      this.currentListView = "comment";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In the list-comments component I am iterating over the items in the project array. When the user clicks one comment in the list the component emits an event **showComment** to Main.vue (with passing an item object from the array).

In Main.vue the emit triggers showComment where I am setting the passed object to a data variable **selectedComment** (I guess this is the point where the Vue reactivity gets lost). selectedComment is bind to the list-comment component which gets activated to show a detail view.

At this point the single item object in the detail-view is not reactive anymore.

**Detail view component, where I am showing a single comment:**

In the detail view nothing special happens. I am not modifying the object directly

```
<template>
  <div id="list-comment">
      ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from "axios";

export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      newReply: "",
    };
  },
  props: {
    selectedComment: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    deleteConversation(id) {
      this.$store.dispatch("deleteConversation", {
        commentId: this.selectedComment._id,
        conversationId: id,
        currentProjectToEdit: "",
      });
    },
    onSubmitConversation() {
      if (this.newReply.length) {
        this.$emit("submitConversation", {
          pageId: "",
          commentId: this.selectedComment._id,
          reply: this.newReply,
        });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**List-view component, where one single item can be selected**

```
<template>
  <div id="list-comment">
    <div
      id="list-card"
      class="list-card-hover"
      v-for="(item, index) in project[0].comments"
      :key="index"
      @click="showComment(item)"
    >
      <div>{{ item.comment }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: {
    project: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    showComment(item) {
      this.$emit("showComment", item);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How could I keep the reactivity of my Vue-App? What would be a better approach?

Comment: Have you tried using vue devtools to ensure that the computed property is updating in `currentListView` (the first snippet)?

Comment: All computed properties are updating accordingly. Just the detail view with `selectedComment` is not reactive. I assume that the reactivity of `selectedComment` gets lost, because I am assigning it to a data property after emitting an event from `list-comments`. But how could I pass it to `list-comment` in another, better way? There are probably better patterns for achieving this.

Comment: I have a theory, I am going to post it as an answer, if it is incorrect let me know

Answer (score 0):

Detail view is using the index number as the key, thus stripping vue of its reactivity. As the key is not updating thus triggering an update.

First off let's assume that each comment in `project[0].comments` has an id or unique value of some kind.

Instead of binding `key` to index, we will bind it to the unique value.

```html
<div
  id="list-card"
  class="list-card-hover"
  v-for="item in project[0].comments"
  :key="index.id"
  @click="showComment(item)"
>
      <div>{{ item.comment }}</div>
</div>
```

If we do not have a unique key we can bind to, there are two options:

1. Create one (this might need to be server-side depending on your use case)
2. We can watch for the prop data to change, and force re-rendering

Obviously, #1 is a much better solution than number 2, but for demonstration's sake, this is how we would implement it.

```
<template>
  <div id="list-comment" :key="updateCount">
    <div
      id="list-card"
      class="list-card-hover"
      v-for="(item, index) in project[0].comments"
      :key="index"
      @click="showComment(item)"
    >
      <div>{{ item.comment }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
        updateCount:0,
    };
  },
  props: {
    project: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  watch:{
    project:{
        deep:true,
        handler(){
            this.updateCount++;
        }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showComment(item) {
      this.$emit("showComment", item);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Also, I assume the project has a unique ID, you could pass that as a prop, and use that unique ID as the key.

Comment: I have tried your approach by changing he index to item._id in the list view. Doesn't work either. You are referencing to the list-view component. Actually in the list-view everything is reactive. (sorry, probably my fault: I have added headlines before the code snippets to make this clearer). The problem is within the detail-view component where I am passing an object by prior assigning it to a data variable. I guess thats the issue. According to this article that could be the reason for losing reactivity: https://michaelnthiessen.com/debugging-guide-why-your-component-isnt-updating/

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have found a solution now - maybe there are better patterns but what I basically did now, was that from the list view I am emitting an event with just the _id of the object.

**List-view component:**

```
<div
   id="webcheck-guru-list-card"
   class="webcheck-guru-list-card-hover"
   v-for="item in project[0].comments"
   :key="item._id"
   @click="showComment(item._id)"
>
```

In my **Main.vue file** I am storing this _id in the selectedComment variable:

```
showComment(comment) {
   this.selectedComment = comment;
   this.currentListView = "comment";
},
```

Then I have created a new computed property that gives me back the selected comment (based on the _id) from my (Vuex) array:

```
getSelectedComment() {
   if (this.project.length && this.selectedComment.length) {
     return this.project[0].comments.filter(
       (comment) => comment._id == this.selectedComment
     );
   } else {
     return [];
   }
},
```

This new computed property is bind to my detail-view component. This way everything is reactive.

```
<list-comment
   v-else-if="currentListView == 'comment'"
   :selectedComment="getSelectedComment"
   @submitConversation="submitConversation"
/>
```

Maybe there is a better solution/pattern in Vue for this - I thought I can just easily pass objects around without losing reactivity.

Happy if somebody else can suggest a better way!